# Spring JpaRepository getOne() for table with PK as String

Tags: java, sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot with a JpaRepository.  I have a table defined with a PK that is a String.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    uuid uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY,
    url text NOT NULL,
    status status DEFAULT 'pending' NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);
```

**Question**

In the JpaRepository, how do I do the equivalent of `getOne(uuid)`? (`getOne(uuid)` receives a paramater type Long)  i.e. How do I retrieve one row for a uuid that is type String?

**Code**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mytable")
public class MyTableEntity {

    public enum Status {
        pending,
        complete,
        processing,
        failed
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuid")
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String uuid;

    @Column(name = "url", nullable = false)
    private String url;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "photo_status", nullable = false)
    //@Type( type = "pgsql_enum" )
    private Status status;

    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime created_at;
```

Repostory

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyTableEntity, Long> {
}
```

Comment: Show us your repository definition.

Comment: If it takes a Long, it means you have chose Long as the generic type for the ID of the repository, although it's a String. Just use the correct generic type.

Comment: maybe you are searching for the findById method. (Optional<T> findById(ID primaryKey): Returns the entity for the given id. ) See: https://www.concretepage.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-crudrepository-example

Comment: @JBNizet, thanks for the reply. I am a bit confused, because gen_random_uuid() generates a random String. So I don't think I can change the type to Long.  (I cannot change the SQL script).

Comment: Show us definition of your repository class because you probably have given `Long` as generic type parameter in `JpaRepository` for your primary key type.

Comment: @KeukenkastjeXYZ, thanks for the reply. I can used findById, but that only has a Long parameter. My PK is type String.

Comment: @michalk, thanks for the reply.  My repository is empty.  I can add the relevant methods, but I am not sure what it should be to findBy(String) or getOne(String). Code example added to the main question above.

Comment: I never advised to change the return type of gen_random_uuid. I advisesd to use the right generic type: String, when defining your repository: `MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyTableEntity, **String**>`

Comment: Also note that you should very rarely use getOne(). Use findById(). getOne() doesn't even check if the entity exists. it returns an uninitialized proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if your entity has String key you can use such declaration of your `Repository` :

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyTableEntity, String> {
}
```

Now if you want to get entity by id, which is of type `String`, you can use for example :

```
private void someMethod() {
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    MyTableEntity myEntity = myRepository.getOne(uuid.toString());
}
```

If you look at `JpaRepository` definition it expects first type to be your Entity class, and second is type of the key of this entity :

```
public interface JpaRepository<T, ID> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID>, QueryByExampleExecutor<T>
```